# How can I pre-fill a substitute command with the result of the previous `*` search in the position where the {string} goes?

Tags: vim

I currently use the following mapping to substitute the result of the last search pattern with a new word in the entire buffer:

```
nnoremap <Leader>sa :%s///g<left><left>
```

What I would like is to put the result of the last search pattern where the new word goes.

Example:

1. suppose my cursor is standing on the word "hello"
2. Then I press `*`
3. Then I invoke the mapping with `<Leader>sa`

At this point, my command line is filled with `:%s///g`. What I would like to have is `:%s//hello/g`.

I tried the mapping below, but it adds the whole word delimeters (`\<` and `\>`) which I don't want.

```
nnoremap <Leader>sa :%s///g<left><left><C-r>/
```

Comment: What would be the point of `:%s/\<hello\>/hello/g`, exactly?

Comment: The starting point for the substitution. Very often when renaming a variable, I just want to append a number or an extra word to potentially long words.

Comment: Then why don't you use `:help s/\&`, as in `:%s//&/g`?

Comment: I didn't know about this but it doesn't seem to help. For example, if I want to rename "ThisIsAVeryLongVariable" to "ThisIsAVeryLongVariable2" I still have to write the entire "ThisIsAVeryLongVariable2"... right? With your other solution, I just need to type the extra "2", which is exactly what I want. The only problem is that I want support for star search in visual mode as well. And you are right, that should have been more clear in the question.

Comment: The original question shouldn't have referred to the "results of a star search" but rather to "the content of the search register".

Comment: `&` represents the whole match so `:%s/foo/&2/g` substitutes every `foo` with `foo2`, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Interesting. But what if I want to go from "ThisIsAVeryLongVariable2" to "ThisIsAVeryLongVariable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--- EDIT ---

After some much needed clarification, I think that the simplest approach is to use `:help s/\&` in the replacement part of your substitution:

```
nnoremap <key> :%s//&/g<left><left>
```

If you really need a more visually explicit method, you can trim the `\<` and the `\>`, like this:

```
nnoremap <key> :%s//<C-r>=substitute(@/,'\\<\\|\\>','','g')<CR>/g<left><left>
```

which should get you something like this:

```
:%s//hello/g
```

with the cursor after `hello`, ready for further editing.

--- ENDEDIT ---

In command-line mode, `:help c_ctrl-r_ctrl-w` inserts the word under the cursor:

```
nnoremap <key> :%s///g<left><left><C-r><C-w>
```

Comment: Hmm this solution does not support visual searches with * of potentially multiple words. Using the result of the last search pattern would.

Comment: 1. `*` is a normal mode command with no visual mode counterpart (`*` does something else in visual mode). 2. You didn't mention anything "visual" in your question.

Comment: Right. I've been using vim-slash for so long that I forgot that that package is providing that functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much! and sorry for the much needed clarification.

Answer (score 2):

<cword> gets the word under the cursor, but you have to call expand and send a carriage return

`nnoremap <Leader>sa :%s///g<left><left><C-r>=expand("<cword>")<CR>`

One way to support visual selections and multiple words is to yank the text you want to replace then search for it with `<C-r>"`

`nnoremap <Leader>sa :%s///g<left><left><C-r>"`

You would make a visual selection, press `y`, then `<leader>sa` to replace, or `/<C-r>"` to search.

Edit

After reading the clarifications above, here is a different way to do (almost) the same thing:

1. Make a visual selection
2. Press `*`
3. Type `cgn<C-r>"2` (e.g. change "ThisIsAVeryLongVariable" to "ThisIsAVeryLongVariable2")
4. Each press of `.` will repeat the substitution

Comment: Hmm this solution does not support visual searches with * of potentially multiple words. Using the result of the last search pattern would. (By the way, you included an extra `/` at the end of the mapping that should be dropped)

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you are prepared to use 'y' instead of '*' it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. I won't accept it because the one above has the exact solution I was looking for.